# Are most vaccum pumps isothermal?

Tags: vacuum, vacuum-pumps

Because adiabatic processes would lead to a high temperature rise due to the high reduction in pressure (from 1 atm to roughly 0 atm).

Comment: Afaik compression causes an increase in temperature - basically how diesel engines work... so reversing the compression process means?

Comment: iso-anything is an idealisation to make calculations easier

Comment: Ok, thanks. I need easier calculations.